# Create powershell alias for . $profile

Tags: powershell

I want to create a set of aliases in a file that I can update, then invoke an alias `aa` so that the file executes and I am provided with the new aliases in the current session. Ultimately I wanted these aliases available automatically on PS startup so I am using `C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1` to put them in. Right now it looks like:

```
$psdir="C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\WindowsPowerShell"  

function Reload-Profile{
  # . ${profile} DOES NOT WORK
  # Write-Host ${profile}
  # Write-Host $profile
  # powershell $profile DOES NOT WORK      
  # Get-ChildItem "${psdir}\*.ps1" | %{.$_} DOES NOT WORK
  Write-Host "Custom PowerShell Environment Loaded" 
}
function Edit-Profile
{
  powershell_ise.exe $profile
}
Set-Alias show Get-ChildItem
Set-Alias show2 Get-ChildItem
Set-Alias aa Reload-Profile
Set-Alias ep Edit-Profile
```

How can I do this so that the aliases are loaded on startup, yet I can also update them with an `aa` alias and have them brought into the current session?

Comment: `Add-Type 'using System.Management.Automation; using System.Management.Automation.Runspaces; [Cmdlet("Reload", "Profile")] public class ReloadProfileCmdlet : PSCmdlet { protected override void EndProcessing() { InvokeCommand.InvokeScript(". $profile", false, PipelineResultTypes.Output|PipelineResultTypes.Error, null); } }' -PassThru | Select -First 1 -ExpandProperty Assembly | Import-Module; Set-Alias aa Reload-Profile`

Comment: @PetSerAl No wonder I couldn't figure it out. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If the original author of the comment that contained the following code decides to post it as an answer, just add a comment to this answer and I will remove it. As it has been two days I don't really expect him to. Meanwhile this should give people a better idea of what is actually happening.

```
# https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-type
# Create a new cmdlet Reload-Profile using C# code and import it
Add-Type '
using System.Management.Automation;
using System.Management.Automation.Runspaces;

// https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878294(v=vs.85).aspx
[Cmdlet("Reload", "Profile")]
public class ReloadProfileCmdlet : PSCmdlet {
    protected override void EndProcessing()
    {
        // https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms568378(v=vs.85).aspx
        // Runs $profile without parameters in the current context and displays the output and error
        InvokeCommand.InvokeScript(". $profile", false, PipelineResultTypes.Output | PipelineResultTypes.Error, null);
    }
}' -PassThru | Select -First 1 -ExpandProperty Assembly | Import-Module;
# Setup an alias for the new cmdlet
Set-Alias aa Reload-Profile
```

For better readability/highlighting the C# code standalone:

```cs
using System.Management.Automation;
using System.Management.Automation.Runspaces;

// https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878294(v=vs.85).aspx
[Cmdlet("Reload", "Profile")]
public class ReloadProfileCmdlet : PSCmdlet {
    protected override void EndProcessing()
    {
        // https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms568378(v=vs.85).aspx
        // Runs $profile without parameters in the current context and displays the output and error
        InvokeCommand.InvokeScript(". $profile", false, PipelineResultTypes.Output | PipelineResultTypes.Error, null);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is, that `Reload-Profile` is a function and when you invoke it, it will create new scope for itself. When you then invoke `. $profile`, it will not create new scope for profile, but it still be invoked inside `Reload-Profile` scope. Thus, when `Reload-Profile` ends, the scope will be discarded. So, you need to invoke `Reload-Profile` with dot invoke operator as well: `. Reload-Profile` or `. aa`, if you use alias.

I assume, your real question is *"How to make `aa` command in a way, which does not require to use dot invoke operator?"*

The answer will be to use compiled cmdlet instead of PowerShell function, because PowerShell does not create new scope for cmdlet invocation. That cmdlet can then invoke `. $profile` in current scope.

```
Add-Type @‘
    using System.Management.Automation;
    using System.Management.Automation.Runspaces;
    [Cmdlet("Reload", "Profile")]
    public class ReloadProfileCmdlet : PSCmdlet {
        protected override void EndProcessing() {
            InvokeCommand.InvokeScript(
                ". $profile",
                false,
                PipelineResultTypes.Output | PipelineResultTypes.Error,
                null
            );
        }
    }
’@ -PassThru | Select -First 1 -ExpandProperty Assembly | Import-Module
Set-Alias aa Reload-Profile
```

P.S.
I recommend you to use different verb instead of `Reload`, because `Reload` is not included in a list of recommended verbs, thus `Import-Module` will issue warning, when you import `Reload-Profile` into your session.